# Jquery Facebox plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebox

I downloaded facebox from famspam.com/facebox.
Then I added facebox.js to be in public/javascripts folder, and facebox.css in public/stylesheets

Then I included this files in my application.html.erb AFTER original Jquery library ver 1.4

The last, I set a rel attribute to my a href tags to try to use Facebox, but it doesn't appear. When clicking on the link with `rel="facebox"`, I just see a picture in my current browser tab.

Please, help me with facebox.

Comment: I used facebox many times myself, so you must have done something wrong, maybe pasting some code would help..

Answer (score 4):

Did you call facebox() onLoad?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox() 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to set where is the images (close image and load image)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.facebox.settings.closeImage ='http://www.yoursite.com/functions/closelabel.png'
$.facebox.settings.loadingImage = 'http://www.yoursite.com/functions/loading.gif'
$('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();   
});
```