# facebox is not working properly in scala

Tags: javascript, ajax, scala, facebox

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/facebox.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link   href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/facebox.css")" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script>   
</script>
<body>

<a href="#info" rel="facebox">text</a>
<div id="info" style="display:none;">
  hello world
</div> 


</body>
```

Facebox and div tag are not showing.I am beginner of ajax so please help me .

Comment: why are you including 2 jQuerys? 1.9.0 and 1.9.1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Facebox plugin doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176141/jquery-facebox-plugin-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox()
})
```